# String containing HTML with PHP tags, execute the PHP and inject into the HTML

Tags: php, html

I have a string containing HTML with PHP tags containing PHP code as follows:

```
$str = "<div>
  Colors:<br/>
  <?php
    foreach ($colors as $c) {
      echo $c . "<br/>"
    }
  ?>
</div>"
```

What is the best way to evaluate the PHP code and inject it back into the string? Much like what would happen if the string content was just run as a single PHP page. I was looking at doing something like:

```
$html_php_split = preg_split("/(<\?php|\?>)/", $str);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($html_php_split); $i++) {
        if ($i % 2) {
            // eval code
        }
        else {
            // keep string
        }
    }
```

But this causes issues if the PHP tag is at the the start of the string. This could be solved with some extra conditionals but this all seems very convoluted for what I want to achieve. Is there a better way?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe you can evaluate your code with this way:

```
ob_start();
    include $filename; // File with your String
    $contents = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

ob_start: This function will turn output buffering on. While output buffering is active no output is sent from the script (other than headers), instead the output is stored in an internal buffer. Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

Comment: This works, thank you! Still a bit messy that I have to save and then import the string from a file but it's better that my solution.